# Trillian no longer showing users "Last seen..." status

Tags: trillian

I'm using **Trillian** (just their built-messenger); not connected to any other IM's etc and it usually shows the last time the user was seen, but now all of a sudden it just says they're *offline*; before it would show something like *Last seen 4 hours ago*.

Is there a setting I may have accidentally changed or would this be caused by something else!?

**Edit:** I *was* using **V5.6 (Build 5) Free** but have since updated to **V6 (Build 58) Free** however the issue still exists.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such setting in the (at least in the latest version of) Trillian which would cause last seen to be off.

Comment: P.S. - my reputation here is less than 50 so I can't comment on your question but It would be helpful if you can provide some more details like, What version and build of Trillian are you using?

Comment: I have updated my question with the version/build I am using.

Comment: Did you try to re-install it? It looks like it's configuration has been changed plus are you using on PC or Trillian app? Also, this problem is with all IM account like google talk, facebook or just Trillian account?

Comment: Well I didn't really see a need to reinstall it since I upgraded to 6. Using on a PC and only Trillian Account as that;s all I use.

Comment: Click on the Trillian connection icon at the top of the contact list and then click on "Show Status Window".  That will open a window that tells a little about the connection. Can you please tell what it says?

Comment: Just connection details... one of note was "Connection to ASTRA has failed: system errorcode "0"." but then it seemed to succeed moments after with stuff like "TLS established using..." and "Bound to resource..." and "You have successfully connected to Trillian.".

Comment: The "errorcode 0" usually means that there's a firewall that's blocking the connection. Please make sure your firewall setting is such that Trillian can pass through Port 3158. Hope this will help. Goodluck.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause Trillian to not be able to connect at all - not just cause a status away msg to show up?

Comment: ...either way I checked and Trillian is allowed by the firewall.